# MDI : name of file on the tab

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mdi, filenames

I have an MDI application that initially doesn't have the main window open. When you click on file and select new, it opens a new tab with the default file name on it.

My application should work like this, when you click on file and select new, a dialog box comes out asking for the name of the file you want to create. After clicking "Ok", the name you input on the textbox should appear on the tab.

How do you set the name on the tab?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override [CDocTemplate::SetDefaultTitle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/32hy02fd(VS.80).aspx).